# Factory function for mypy `TypedDict`

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I want to be able to write a function that checks if a dictionary confirms to my `TypedDict`, however I can't get the generic type right. So the resulting function should be something like:

```
T = typing.Generic('T', bound=...) # This is `bound=...` something I want to find out

def check_typeddict(value: dict, to_type: typing.Type[T]) -> T:
    # do some type checking
    return typing.cast(T, value)

check_type(MyTypedDict, {'a': 5})
```

Things like using `TypedDict` or `dict` for the `bound` value do not work, is this simply not possible (yet) or I'm I missing something else?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be using `Generic` -- you want `TypeVar` instead. We use `Generic` to declare that some class ought to be treated as being generic; we use `TypeVar` to create a type variable (which we can then use to help make generic classes or functions).

You also have the arguments swapped in your your call to `check_type` (which should also probably be `check_typeddict`).

Putting these all together, a functioning version of your code looks like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type, cast
from mypy_extensions import TypedDict

class MyTypedDict(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: int

T = TypeVar('T')

def check_typeddict(value: dict, to_type: Type[T]) -> T:
    # do some type checking
    return cast(T, value)

out = check_typeddict({'a': 5}, MyTypedDict)
reveal_type(out)  # Mypy reports 'MyTypedDict'
```

No bound should be necessary in this case.

Comment: Oh sorry I was using `TypeVar`, it was simply a typo. Sorry about that. The problem with not using a base is that any value can be passed to `check_typeddict`, not only `TypedDict`. It seems that bounding to `Mapping` works, however that still allows `dict` to be passed, which I would prefer to reject.