# Function for getting type of TypedDict value that works with static type checker

Tags: python, dictionary, mypy, python-typing

I am looking to make a Python (3.8+) function that is:

- Input: key of a `TypedDict`
- Output:

  - Returns the value (easy)
  - Is appropriately type hinted (where I am stuck)

Here is a code sample to help explain:

```py
from typing import Any, Literal, TypedDict

class Foo(TypedDict):
    bar: int
    baz: str
    spam: Any

foo = Foo(bar=0, baz="hi", spam=1.0)

def get_type(key: Literal["bar", "baz"]):  # How to type hint the return here?
    """Function that get TypedDict's value when passed a key."""
    val = foo[key]
    # This works via intelligent indexing
    # SEE: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#intelligent-indexing
    reveal_type(val)  # mypy: Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.int, builtins.str]'
    return val

fetched_type = get_type("bar")
reveal_type(fetched_type)  # mypy: Revealed type is 'Any'
# I would like this to have output: 'int'
```

In case you can't tell, the static type checker I am using is `mypy`.

The function I have above `get_type` gets halfway there with [intelligent indexing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#intelligent-indexing), but I am not sure how to type hint the return of `get_type`.

What type hint should I put for the return of `get_type`?

---

**Research**

Both of these questions

- [Factory function for mypy `TypedDict`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747473/factory-function-for-mypy-typeddict)
- [How to statically get TypeVar parameters from a Generic for use in static type checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354233/how-to-statically-get-typevar-parameters-from-a-generic-for-use-in-static-type-c)

provide answers using `TypeVar`.  Is there some way of using `TypeVar` with `TypedDict`?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, you could use `@overload` for `get_type`:

```
from typing import Any, Literal, TypedDict, Union, overload

class Foo(TypedDict):
    bar: int
    baz: str
    spam: Any

foo = Foo(bar=0, baz="hi", spam=1.0)


@overload
def get_type(key: Literal["bar"]) -> int: ...

@overload
def get_type(key: Literal["baz"]) -> str: ...
    

def get_type(key: Literal["bar", "baz"]) -> Union[int, str]:
    """Function that get TypedDict's value when passed a key."""
    val = foo[key]
    reveal_type(val)  # mypy: Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.int, builtins.str]'
    return val

fetched_type = get_type("bar")
reveal_type(fetched_type)  # mypy: Revealed type is 'builtins.int'
```

Comment: Thank you very much @alex_noname, this works!  In my actual use case `TypedDict`, there are a lot of keys.  Using this solution, the `get_type` method have quite a lot of `overload`s, and will not have a "light weight" feel.  I will hold out before marking the answer, in case there's a less verbose way of solving the problem.